# Ceiling fan with remote for fan/light and two wall switches

Tags: wiring, lighting, remote-control

Wire Colors/Locations

Ceiling - Copper, Black, White, Red
Ceiling Fan Mount - Green/Yellow
Ceiling Fan Remote - Yellow, Blue, White, Black
Ceiling Fan - Black, White, Blue, Green/Yellow
Trying to connect all wires correctly and have wall switches work

Comment: Is this a new install or are you replacing the fan?  If replacing, include pictures of how it was originally wired.  If a new install, include pictures of existing wiring at ceiling and in switch boxes.

Comment: New build house with fan pre-wire.  What was there from builder was a light.  Does that help?

Comment: What was the light connected to?

Comment: Does "two wall switches" mean "two switches on opposite sides of the room"? (a.k.a. "3-way switches") or does it mean "two switches next to each other"? (a.k.a. fan and light)

Comment: What make/model of ceiling fan are you trying to hook up?  Are you OK with sacrificing the remote/receiver that came with the fan in favor of some other system?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Given the non-response on our questions, and the existence of what looks like a dead-nuts perfect answer elsewhere... I'm voting to flag this as a duplicate.